# Javascript code isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm quite the newbie at Javascript and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong with this code. Whenever I run the code it doesn't run properly and I have no idea what to change with it. I'm trying to get it to loop through 5 buttons and replace the innerHTML of the button with what the user has typed in an input box. So for example, if the user typed 'pie' in the input box and clicked button 4, the innerHTML of button 4 would be renamed to pie. Here's my code:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

function click() {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        if (this.id == "b" + x) {
            document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML = inputValue;
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("b" + i).onclick = click;
}
```

Comment: this.id refers to the button.

Comment: You should use this,  document.getElementById("b" + i).onclick = function() { click()  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the line that extracts the contents on your input box inside your click handler:

```
function click() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        if (this.id == "b" + x) {
            document.getElementById("b" + x).innerHTML = inputValue;
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("b" + i).onclick = click;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mt7n/)

But actually, you don't need the loop inside the click handler at all. You can just do this:

```
function click() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    this.innerHTML = inputValue;
}
```

[Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mt7n/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   document.getElementById("b" + i).onclick = function(){
         this.innerHTML = inputValue;
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this much easier:

```
function click(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    this.innerHTML = inputValue;
}
```